# Jmeter class not found exception when executing test for grpc endpoint

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, grpc

I am running into an error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ***APIGrpc when trying to run Jmeter for my grpc endpoint. Not sure why Grpc is being appended at the last, not sure if that is causing issue. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) means that the class you're trying to use is not in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Make sure to put the class (along with dependencies if any) to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation or to the folder where `user.classpath` [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) is pointing to

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the changes.

With regards to `Grpc` postfix its generated in the proto folder so it's kind of expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have uploaded the jar files of the protos as well as the jar files of related dependency protos, however still facing the same issue.